# How do you set different colors per QSurfaceDataRow in a Q3DSurface?

Tags: c++, qt, 3d, data-visualization

How do you set different colors on specific QSurfaceDataRows that are within a QSurfaceDataArray on a Q3DSurface?

I was able to set all the data to one specific color with:

`surfaceGraph->seriesList().at(0)->setBaseColor(Qt::gray);`

and I want to leave most of it gray, but on occasion I want it to make a couple different rows within the data different colors. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to apply a Texture over the surface.

You have to create a related image with color you need and apply that to the surface
"->setTexture"